How can I change my Unity Wave Function Collapse algorithm so that it properly propagates the neighbor tile options?
I'm trying to implement a wave function collapse algorithm in my unity game. Each cell has a list of possible tiles, and each tile has its own up/down/left/right rules. I'm trying to solve an issue ive been having where impossible tiles will be placed because the possible options aren't being propagated to all tiles
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class WaveFunction : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject generationManager;
    public int dimensions;
    public Tile[] tileObjects;
    public Tile fallbackTile;
    public Cell cellObj;
    
    private List<Cell> gridComponents;
    private int iterations = 0;

    void Awake()
    {
        gridComponents = new List<Cell>();
        InitializeGrid();
    }

    void InitializeGrid()
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < dimensions; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < dimensions; x++)
            {
                Cell newCell = Instantiate(cellObj, new Vector2(x, y), Quaternion.identity, transform);
                newCell.CreateCell(false, tileObjects);
                gridComponents.Add(newCell);
            }
        }

        StartCoroutine(CalculateEntropy());
    }

    IEnumerator CalculateEntropy()
    {
        List<Cell> tempGrid = GetUncollapsedCells();

        if (tempGrid.Count == 0)
            yield break;

        Cell minOptionsCell = tempGrid.OrderBy(c => c.tileOptions.Length).First();
        int minOptions = minOptionsCell.tileOptions.Length;

        tempGrid.RemoveAll(c => c.tileOptions.Length > minOptions);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.01f);

        CollapseCell(tempGrid);
    }

    void CollapseCell(List<Cell> tempGrid)
    {
        if (tempGrid == null || tempGrid.Count == 0)
        {
            Debug.LogError("No cells available for collapse.");
            return;
        }

        float totalWeightSum = tempGrid.Sum(c => c.tileOptions.Sum(t => t.weight));
        float randomWeight = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, totalWeightSum);

        Cell cellToCollapse = null;
        Tile selectedTile = null;

        foreach (var cell in tempGrid)
        {
            foreach (var tile in cell.tileOptions)
            {
                randomWeight -= tile.weight;
                if (randomWeight <= 0)
                {
                    cellToCollapse = cell;
                    selectedTile = tile;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (cellToCollapse != null)
                break;
        }
        if (cellToCollapse == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Failed to select a cell to collapse.");
            Instantiate(generationManager);
            Destroy(transform.gameObject);
            return;
        }

        cellToCollapse.collapsed = true;
        cellToCollapse.tileOptions = new Tile[] { selectedTile };

        Instantiate(selectedTile, cellToCollapse.transform.position, Quaternion.identity, cellToCollapse.transform);

        Generate();
    }

    void Generate()
    {
        List<Cell> newGenerationCell = new List<Cell>(gridComponents);

        for (int y = 0; y < dimensions; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < dimensions; x++)
            {
                int index = x + y * dimensions;
                Cell currentCell = gridComponents[index];

                if (currentCell.collapsed)
                {
                    newGenerationCell[index] = currentCell;
                    continue;
                }

                List<Tile> options = new List<Tile>(tileObjects);
                UpdateNeighborsOptions(x, y, options);
                newGenerationCell[index].RecreateCell(options.ToArray());
            }
        }

        gridComponents = newGenerationCell;
        iterations++;

        if (iterations < dimensions * dimensions)
        {
            StartCoroutine(CalculateEntropy());
        }
    }

    void UpdateNeighborsOptions(int x, int y, List<Tile> options)
    {
        UpdateNeighborOptions(x, y - 1, options, tile => tile.upNeighbours);
        UpdateNeighborOptions(x + 1, y, options, tile => tile.leftNeighbours);
        UpdateNeighborOptions(x, y + 1, options, tile => tile.downNeighbours);
        UpdateNeighborOptions(x - 1, y, options, tile => tile.rightNeighbours);
    }

    void UpdateNeighborOptions(int x, int y, List<Tile> options, Func<Tile, Tile[]> neighborGetter)
    {
        if (x >= 0 && x < dimensions && y >= 0 && y < dimensions)
        {
            Cell neighborCell = gridComponents[x + y * dimensions];
            List<Tile> validOptions = new List<Tile>();

            foreach (Tile possibleOption in neighborCell.tileOptions)
            {
                validOptions.AddRange(neighborGetter(possibleOption));
            }

            CheckValidity(options, validOptions);
        }
    }

    void CheckValidity(List<Tile> optionList, List<Tile> validOption)
    {
        optionList.RemoveAll(tile => !validOption.Contains(tile));
    }

    List<Cell> GetUncollapsedCells()
    {
        return gridComponents.FindAll(c => !c.collapsed);
    }
}


I've tried a bunch of different solutions to this now and I just can't seem to figure out how I can propagate the options without it just crashing.
I've tried a bunch of stuff like recursively updating neighbors, or using an alternate propagate function but it always seems to just crash unity due to an infinite loop.
